# Cannot change lockscreen Calender widget's language

Tags: greeter, language

I changed system language and regional settings to United States, top Bar calender shows English only. Yet the lockscreen widget for calender i.e next to log on screen it shows Arabic. Any workarounds?

Tried updating language using terminal and settings menu. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the date

Comment: I presume yes. Next to logon column, there it is for ex. 26(today date), Arabic word, Arabic word, and then down the time. I can't read Arabic, but I presume it's Week day and month. May be like 26 April, Tuesday.

Comment: I have the same problem but since my location is Sri Lanka it is in Sinhala. I would like it to be English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GUI method , does not always work

Go to **Settings** > **Language and Region**. You will see something like
[image]

Then click the unblock button and enter your password. In formats select your correct region and language .It is India (English) for you , I set United States because there isn't a English format for my location and I think that this is a bug with elementary OS.

Click the **Set System Language** button and then the **Set Language** button

Logout and back in to see the changes. Restart to see the changes on the greeter

### Terminal method , always works

Run the following in a terminal
For your location it is

```
localectl set-locale "LANG=en_IN.utf8"
```

For my location it is

```
localectl set-locale "LANG=en_LK.utf8"
```

For other locations modify the command

Comment: I used this first method and it worked very well. In fact, I did this earlier, but the mistake I did was, I didn't use unblock button. Now it seems perfect. Appreciate it.

Comment: Consider upvoting if you find this very useful

Comment: I don't know how to up vote. Can you guide me?